# Why is using the '-execdir' action insecure for directory which is in the PATH?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, find

Why is it insecure to use the combination of `-execdir` action of find while using `-exec` isn't?

When I'm running the below command I'm getting the following prompt message:

```bsh
/path/to/currentDir/$ find . -type f -name 'partOfFileNames*' -execdir rm -- {} +

find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure 
in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory 
from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)
```

What may caused this prompt appearing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You could run the wrong program. Someone could make you run their program.

The `-execdir` action runs your command from the directory that contains the file(s) found. *When `$PATH` contains relative paths, such as `.` or anything that doesn't start with `/`*, `-execdir` is insecure because a directory where a file is found (or another directory resolved relative to it) could also contain an executable of the same name as the one you are trying to run. That potentially untrusted executable would then get run instead.

This could be deliberately exploited by another user to cause you to run their program, which might cause harm or breach data security, instead of the program you are trying to run. Or, less often, it might simply result in the wrong program inadvertently being run, even without anyone trying to make the problem happen.

If everything in your `PATH` environment variable is an absolute path, this error should not occur, even if the directory you're searching and `-execdir`ing from *is* contained in `PATH`. (I've checked that this works.) If you believe you don't have any relative directories in `$PATH` but are still getting this error, please update your question with details including the output of `echo "$PATH"`.

#### A concrete example.

As an example of what could go wrong, suppose:

- Alice has `.` in her `$PATH` because she wants to be able to run programs in whatever directory she's `cd`'d to, without bothering to prepend their names with `./`.
- Alice's frenemy Eve has shared `/home/eve/shared` with Alice.
- Alice wants statistics (lines, words, bytes) on the `.c` files Eve has shared with her.

So Alice runs:

```
find ~eve/shared -name \*.c -execdir wc {} \;
```

Unfortunately for Alice, Eve has created her own script, named it `wc`, set it executable (`chmod +x`), and placed it clandestinely in one of the directories under `/home/eve/shared`. Eve's script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/wc "$@"
do_evil    # Eve replaces this command with whatver evil she wishes to do
```

So when Alice uses `find` with `-execdir` to run `wc` on the files Eve has shared, and it gets to files in the same directory as Eve's custom `wc` script, Eve's `wc` runs--with all of Alice's privileges!

(Being crafty, Eve has made her `wc` script act as a wrapper for the system `wc`, so Alice won't even know something has gone wrong, i.e., that *`do_evil`* was run. However, simpler--and also more sophisticated--variations are possible.)

#### How `find` prevents this.

**`find` prevents this security problem from happening** by refusing to take the `-execdir` action when `$PATH` contains a relative directory.

`find` offers two diagnostic messages depending on the specific situation.

- If `.` is in `$PATH`, then (as you've seen) it says:

  `find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)`

  It probably has a special message for the `.` case as it's especially common.
- If a relative path other than `.`--say, *`foo`*--appears in `$PATH` and you run `find` with `-execdir`, it says:

  `` find: The relative path `foo' is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH ``

#### It's better not to have relative paths in `$PATH` at all.

The risk of having `.` or other relative paths in `$PATH` is especially heightened when using a utility that automatically changes the directory, which is why `find` won't let you use `-execdir` in this situation.

But having relative paths, especially `.`, in your `$PATH` is inherently risky and is really best avoided anyway. Consider the fictional situation in the example above. Suppose instead of running `find`, Alice simply `cd`s to `~eve/shared/blah` and runs `wc *.c`. If `blah` contains Eve's `wc` script, *`do_evil`* runs as Alice.

Comment: I don't know if you have heard this before that you would make a very good teacher  :)

Comment: @heemayl all those who write useful stuff on the net, are already teachers :-)

Comment: If `find` refuses to execute a command when `-execdir` is used, then it should be just as secure as `-exec`.

Comment: apparently a trailing `:` also causes this

Answer (score 5):

There is a much detailed information [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml#Options_exec_and_execdir). Another excellent reference is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html). To quote from the first reference:

> The option -execdir  is a more modern option introduced in GNU find
> is an attempt to create a more safe version of -exec. It has the same
> semantic as -exec with two important enhancements:
>
> It always provides absolute path to the file (using relative path to a
> file is really dangerous in case of -exec).
>
> In addition to providing
> absolute path it also checks the PATH variable for safety  (if dot is
> present in the PATH env variable, you can pickup executable from the
> wrong directory)

From second reference:

> The ‘-execdir’ action refuses to do anything if the current directory
> is included in the $PATH environment variable. This is necessary
> because ‘-execdir’ runs programs in the same directory in which it
> finds files – in general, such a directory might be writable by
> untrusted users. For similar reasons, ‘-execdir’ does not allow ‘{}’
> to appear in the name of the command to be run.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer why *"if dot is present in the PATH env variable, you can pickup executable from the wrong directory"*? which **wrong directory**? And why we have to do this for making it **secure**? Thanks

Comment: I hope the second link in my updated post will answer your question

Answer (score 4):

**Set `PATH=/usr/bin`**

This is not ideal, but it tends to solve most use cases, supposing both `find` and the program to be used (`rm` here) are in that directory:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find -execdir rm ...
```

You can just add any missing PATHs as needed.

**`xargs` and `bash -c cd` workaround**

OK, I give up:

```
find . -type f |
  xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'cd "$(dirname "{}")" && pwd && echo "$(basename "{}")"'
```

**`sed` workaround**

A bit less nice than the previous workaround:

```
PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | sed -E 's/(^|:)[^\/][^:]*//g')" find . -execdir echo '{}' \;
```

A testcase:

```
[ "$(printf '/a/b::c/d:/e/f\n' | sed -E 's/(^|:)[^\/][^:]*//g')" = '/a/b:/e/f' ] || echo fail
```

For `rename` specifically, you can also work around with some Perl regex-fu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/finding-multiple-files-recursively-and-renaming-in-linux/54163971#54163971

**RTFS hope crushing**

For those who have hopes that there exists a way to ignore `find`'s opinionatedness, let me crush that with some source:

- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c?h=v4.6.0#n2847
- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c?h=v4.6.0#n2944

From that we see that there seems to be no way to turn off the path checking.

The exact rule it checks is: fail if the `PATH` is either empty or does not start with `/`.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is with the value of system variable `PATH` which contains relative folders in it, so for security reasons `find` command won't allow you to execute binaries, because potentially it can execute wrong programs.

---

So for example, if you have your current dir in your PATH as per warning which you get:

> The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable.

and you'll run your command:

```
find . -type f -name 'partOfFileNames*' -execdir rm -- {} +
```

in case you'll have local script (`rm` with executable flags) containing `rm -fr /` in it, it can remove all your files, because instead of executing expected `/bin/rm`, you'll execute `rm` from the current dir, so probably it's not what you wanted.

---

As a side note, this is known issue in Travis CI ([GH #2811](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2811)) when it fails with the error:

> find: The relative path `./node_modules/.bin' is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

So the solution is to remove affected entry from PATH variable, e.g.

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:\.\/node_modules\/\.bin//'`
```

as proposed by [drogus](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2811#issuecomment-56800296). The progress of this bug, can be followed at [GH #4862](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4862).

---

Here is Bash version workaround:

```
PATH=${PATH//:\.\/node_modules\/\.bin/}
```

Example usage (passing filtered `PATH` to specific command):

```
env PATH=${PATH//:\.\/node_modules\/\.bin/} find . -type f
```

Comment: Here is a `sed` that seems to remove all things `find` does not like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path/1109378#1109378

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to pass custom PATH before the command, e.g.

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -type f -name 'partOfFileNames*' -execdir echo rm -- {} +
```

Above workaround will prevent loading the global `$PATH`, but our own.

---

Here is another example (more flexible), assuming we want to run `cat` command:

```
PATH=$(dirname $(which find)):$(dirname $(which cat)) find /etc -name hosts -execdir cat {} ';'
```

or:

```
PATH=$(dirname $(which cat find) | paste -sd:) find ...
```

by running `$(dirname $(which cat))` we calculate where our command to run is located.