# Move characters from the start of filenames to the end (before extension) and add whitespace

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have ~2000 files in an original naming scheme.

I need to take them all, move the first 4 characters to the end of the filename before the extension, and then add a whitespace before the first 4 characters.

Basically, from:

```
0123 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).jpg
```

to

```
[UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL) 0123.jpg
```

Comment: The numbers are a unique primary ID. They just need to be moved over.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
rename -n 's/^([0-9]+) (.*)\.jpg/$2 $1.jpg/' /path/to/files/*.jpg
```

Sample:

```
0324 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt
0123 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt
0124 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt
```

Results:

```
rename(0123 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt,  [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL) 0123.txt)
rename(0124 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt,  [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL) 0124.txt)
rename(0324 [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL).txt,  [UNKNOWN] (Final Fantasy 9) headshot of Freya Crescent {sketch} (ORIGINAL) 0324.txt)
```

**Note:** Tested with `.txt` files will also work on jpg filenames

Information:

`([0-9]+)`: pick the numbers at the front.

`(.*)`: pick every other thing till the file extension.

`$2 $1.txt`: return the captured groups with the returned group for `numbers` placed close to the file extension `jpg` and add a space before the numbers.

`-n`: run without changing filename so we see what files are changed and what the names are changed to, remove this to rename the files.

Comment: Awesome. This works! But my dumb ass forgot to use the -n flag when I was toying with it.

Is there an easy way to undo what I did with
rename 's/^([0-9]+) (.*)\.*/$2 $1.*/' *.*

Comment: @mattdawolf Use this `rename -n 's/^(.*) ([0-9]*)\.jpg/$2 $1.txt/' *.jpg` to reverse what you did. Remeber to leave the `-n` option and be sure before removing it!

Comment: I corrected the .txt in that but it didn't seem to work. Also what I pasted a few comments up got stripped. </newbie>

`rename 's/^([0-9]+) (.*)\.*/$2 $1.*/' /path/to/files/*.*` is what I ran which gave me this:

`[DanielFox] (character picture) Headshot of Ninetales {digital color} (ELECTRONIC COPY).jpg 0093.*`

Comment: @mattdawolf, Is this `[DanielFox] (character picture) Headshot of Ninetales {digital color} (ELECTRONIC COPY).jpg 0093.*`  how your files are now?

Comment: the rest are done properly. It's just this one subdir I messed up. Should've tarred everything but  I am low on space. x.x

Gotta gegt that 0093 back to the start of the file delete all the crap after the extension, do it to the other 500 files, then rerun the script. That will teach me to not back things up...

Comment: @mattdawolf you want the files there named to `0093 [DanielFox] (character picture) Headshot of Ninetales {digital color} (ELECTRONIC COPY).jpg`, if so use this `rename -n 's/^\.\/(.*)(\.jpg) ([0-9]*)\.\*/$3 $1$2/' ./*` Please test before running! And run from the folder in question

Comment: bless you. meh. shoulda stuck coding in high school but the teacher threw me out of that class. All because I objected to the dress code...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/find.1.html) and [`Shell Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

1. If you don't have [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/prename.1.html) installed (but most probably it's already installed as part of Perl packages).
2. You can perform on all or specified matched file *patterns* "*.jpg" only.
3. It's recursively as `find` nature is.

```bsh
find . -type f -execdir \
    sh -c 'X="[${1#*[}"; Y="${1%% *}"; 
    echo mv -v "$1" "${X%.*} ${Y#./}.${X##*.}"' find-sh '{}' \;
```

**Explanations:**

- `X="[${1#*[}"` (cut-up-to-first-prefix): This removes everything until first `[` seen, and appends `[` back to the pattern.
- `Y="${1%% *}"` (cut-up-to-last-suffix): This removes everything until last space seen starts from end to the beginning of the filename; This will result `./PATTERN` which is `./0123` as example.
- `${X%.*}` (cut-up-to-first-suffix): This removes suffix (ex: `.jpg`).
- `Y="${Y#./}"` (cut-up-to-first-prefix): This removes `./` from variable `Y` and will result PATTERN only from second step which is `0123` now.
- `.${X##*.}"` (cut-up-to-last-prefix): This removes everything until last dot `.` seen starts from beginning to the end of the filename and append back a dot `.`; This will result `.PATTERN` which is `.jpg` now.
- `-execdir` used here to don't result file path by `find` command and it's safe to intact the */path/to/files/*. This will produce [a prompt if you have current directory in your *PATH* or if it contains relative paths which is unsafe](https://askubuntu.com/a/621163/283843).
- `echo` is used for dry run, remove it to have actual rename.